# Application Insights telemetry processor not catching exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I have a custom Telemetry Processor that sends custom exception fields to Application Insights.

For example if I throw a custom exception like this one

```cs
class MyException : Exception
{
   public string AdditionalData { get; set; }
}
```

then it sends `AdditionalData` as a custom app insights field.

```cs
public class CustomExceptionDataTelemetryProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default exception fields that should be ignore because they are part of logs by default
    /// </summary>
    private static IEnumerable<string> _DefaultExceptionFields = new Exception().GetType().GetProperties().Select(e => e.Name);
    private readonly ITelemetryProcessor _next;

    public CustomExceptionDataTelemetryProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        ModifyItem(item);
        _next.Process(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds exception fields as custom data
    /// </summary>
    private void ModifyItem(ITelemetry item)
    {
        if (!(item is ExceptionTelemetry exceptionTelementry))
        {
            return;
        }

        var exception = exceptionTelementry.Exception;
        var exceptionType = exception.GetType();

        foreach (var property in exceptionType.GetProperties())
        {
            // ignore default fields
            if (_DefaultExceptionFields.Contains(property.Name))
            {
                continue;
            }
            
            var value = property.GetValue(exception);
            var serializedValue = (value is string) ? value.ToString() : HttpClientUtils.Serialize(value);
            exceptionTelementry.Properties[property.Name] = serializedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

I register this processor like this

```cs
var telemetryBuilder = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;
telemetryBuilder.Use((next) => new CustomExceptionDataTelemetryProcessor(next));
telemetryBuilder.Build();
```

Everything works fine with `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` version [2.2.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/2.2.1).

If I upgrade to latest version [2.15.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/2.15.0) it still works fine, but I get a warning that the registration code is deprecated so I changed it per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling)

```cs
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<CustomExceptionDataTelemetryProcessor>();
```

But now the exception doesn't get 'caught' anymore by the processor. Only items of type `RequestTelemetry` or `DependencyTelemetry`. No items of type `ExceptionTelemetry`.

I could leave the registration with the old way, but thinking that it might be a sign that something is not quite right and might cause other issues elsewhere.

I tried to remove all initializers and processors before registering my own, but it doesn't help. Something else might be filtering out the exception.

```cs
services.RemoveAll(typeof(ITelemetryInitializer));
services.RemoveAll(typeof(ITelemetryProcessor));
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug to see if error occurs, your custom processor is executed at that time?

Comment: I did debug, processor wasn't executing. Found the solution and posted as answer

Comment: That's weird. It can work well at my side. can you please create a new project in visual studio to test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with version [2.13.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/2.13.1) of `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore`

I also had `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` NuGet package installed with a different version. Removed it and kept only `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore`.

Comment: What about 2.15.0 whereby the registration code has changed, as per your question?

Comment: doesn't work for me with version 2.15.0, might be something wrong with my code though. it works fine with 2.13.1 which is enough for me

Comment: 2.15.0 still doesn't work even after you removed `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights`?

Comment: yes, that's right. tested again
1. thrown an exception in my code
2. added breakpoint into the telemetry processor
3. with version 2.13.1 the breakpoint is hit
4. upgraded package to 2.15.0 (this is the only change I made in the project). breakpoint is not hit anymore

Comment: Would be appreciated if you could report this as an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues

Comment: I created a new ASP.NET Core project and integrated the telemetry processor. It works with version 2.15.0. So it's not actually an issue, it's some kind of mismatch with other packages in my project.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do that research!